# defs and use in a dynamically created page

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I build from scratch a svg document with javascript directives. I first create defs, with IDs

```
<defs><g id="id45"> ... </g></defs>
```

and call them properly.

```
<use xlink:href="#id45" x="0" y="0">
```

Alas, it doesn't display any "used" elements.

However, when I copy paste the result of the javascript generation (Firefox 40.0.3) into a brand new `.html` file, everything is fine. As you may see  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3so1gjv6/1/) (cf. ugly, pink and blue boxes) :

```
<html lang="jap">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>plot</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css">
    </head>
    <body>

<svg viewBox="-10 -10 456 129" width="456px" height="129px" id="kanji_grid">
<defs><g id="kanji_grid_box"><rect height="129" width="129" y="0" x="0"></rect><line y2="129" x2="64.5" y1="0" x1="64.5"></line><line y2="64.5" x2="129" y1="64.5" x1="0"></line></g></defs>
<rect class="frame" height="129" width="456" y="-10" x="-10"></rect><g transform="translate(0, 0)"><use style="fill:blue" xlink:href="#kanji_grid_box" y="10" x="10"></use><path class="main_stroke" d="M53.21,18.37C53.75,20.5,53.47,21.78,52.96,23.62C50.38,33,42.62,52.75,35.75,64C34.36,66.27,34.75,67.5,36.75,67.5C48.38,67.5,65.21,74.98,75.58,83.91C78.14,86.12,80.26,88.42,81.75,90.75"></path><circle class="start_circle" r="6" cy="18.37" cx="53.21"></circle></g><g transform="translate(109, 0)"><use style="fill:blue" xlink:href="#kanji_grid_box" y="10" x="10"></use><path d="M53.21,18.37C53.75,20.5,53.47,21.78,52.96,23.62C50.38,33,42.62,52.75,35.75,64C34.36,66.27,34.75,67.5,36.75,67.5C48.38,67.5,65.21,74.98,75.58,83.91C78.14,86.12,80.26,88.42,81.75,90.75"></path><path class="main_stroke" d="M69.62,42.18C70.12,43.88,70.25,45.75,69.61,48.11C65.93,61.8,54.61,81.6,27,91.75"></path><circle class="start_circle" r="6" cy="42.18" cx="69.62"></circle></g><g transform="translate(218, 0)"><use style="fill:blue" xlink:href="#kanji_grid_box" y="10" x="10"></use><path d="M53.21,18.37C53.75,20.5,53.47,21.78,52.96,23.62C50.38,33,42.62,52.75,35.75,64C34.36,66.27,34.75,67.5,36.75,67.5C48.38,67.5,65.21,74.98,75.58,83.91C78.14,86.12,80.26,88.42,81.75,90.75"></path><path d="M69.62,42.18C70.12,43.88,70.25,45.75,69.61,48.11C65.93,61.8,54.61,81.6,27,91.75"></path><path class="main_stroke" d="M13.88,50.43C17.36,51.82,21.14,51.28,24.76,50.96C44.28,49.26,66.8,46.88,85.37,46.33C89.03,46.22,92.58,46.23,95.99,47.75"></path><circle class="start_circle" r="6" cy="50.43" cx="13.88"></circle></g><g class="final" transform="translate(327, 0)"><path d="M53.21,18.37C53.75,20.5,53.47,21.78,52.96,23.62C50.38,33,42.62,52.75,35.75,64C34.36,66.27,34.75,67.5,36.75,67.5C48.38,67.5,65.21,74.98,75.58,83.91C78.14,86.12,80.26,88.42,81.75,90.75"></path><path d="M69.62,42.18C70.12,43.88,70.25,45.75,69.61,48.11C65.93,61.8,54.61,81.6,27,91.75"></path><path d="M13.88,50.43C17.36,51.82,21.14,51.28,24.76,50.96C44.28,49.26,66.8,46.88,85.37,46.33C89.03,46.22,92.58,46.23,95.99,47.75"></path></g>
</svg>

</body></html>
```

Could it be that dynamically generated `<defs>` are not known soon enough ? How could I circumvent this ?

Here is the function I use to build the whole svg document

```
Node.prototype.svg_grow = function(node_name, node_attr) {
    /*
        node_name is a string
        node_attr is a map of string to string
    */
    var n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", node_name);
    this.appendChild(n);
    if (typeof node_attr !== 'undefined') {
        for (let key in node_attr) {
            n.setAttribute(key, node_attr[key]);
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Then I use this kind of construct :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>
<svg id="kanji_grid">
</svg>
<script>
var s_svg = document.getElementById("kanji_grid");
var s_defs = s_svg.svg_grow('defs');
var s_g = s_defs.svg_grow('g', {'id':"kanji_box"});
s_g.svg_grow('rect', {'x':0, 'y':0, 'width':s+2*b, 'height':s+2*b});
etc...
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to create the xlink:href attribute on the `<use>` element using setAttribute aren't you.

That won't work as you need to use setAttributeNS to create that in the xlink namespace. E.g.

```
node.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", "#id45");
```

Comment: I like this suggestion :)

Comment: with `href` only as name it still work under firefox ?! is it better to put `xlink:href` ?

Comment: It is, which is why I corrected your edit to my answer. I think if you use a serializer on an html document it may not come out right. Erik Dahlström explained it to me once but I've forgotten the exactly what he said. If you want to know, there's this question and answer site right here where you can ask another question. Eric might even tell us :-)